# VB Socket.Send returns "A non blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately."

Tags: file, buffer, send, blocking, transfer

I have a server which can send files to clients requesting them. It works really great with files with size less than 2 gigs. 
However, when file is over 2 gigs, my server here will give me an *overflow error* at **Dim buffer**. I looked for it and found that the buffer size could be (upload.SendBufferSize -1). However, changing this gives me an different error: 
**Upload.Send**: *A non blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.*

I searched it from internet, and one suggest was to try adding Upload.Blocking = True if error occurs, but then I get an error which says Argument is invalid.

Any suggestions to my problem?

```vb
Private Sub UploaderAccept(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim File As IO.FileInfo = ar.AsyncState
    Dim Upload As Socket = UploadServer.EndAccept(ar)

    '--- Determine size of buffer
    Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(File.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim buffer(Upload.SendBufferSize - 1) As Byte
    Dim Sent As Long = 0
    Dim t As Long = 0

    '--- Actual sending
    Do Until Sent >= File.Length
        t = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Upload.Send(buffer, 0, t, SocketFlags.None)

        Sent += t
    Loop

    '--- File transfer done
    fs.Close()

    Upload.BeginDisconnect(False, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnDisconnect), upload)
    Upload.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it myself, in case someone needs it, you cannot do this by changing from async to syncronous.. Just use:

Upload.BeginSend(buffer, 0, t, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnSend), Upload):

```vb
    Do Until Sent >= File.Length
        t = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If t > 0 Then
            Upload.BeginSend(buffer, 0, t, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf UploadOnSend), Upload)
        End If

        Sent += t
        TextUpdate(lblFilePerc, Sent)
    Loop
    Close streams...

Private Sub UploadOnSend(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim upload As Socket = ar.AsyncState
    upload.EndSend(ar)

End Sub
```